# What are fundamental data types in IA-32?

Tags: x86

I would like to know what the fundamental data types of Intel IA-32 architecture are.

I know four of them - bytes(8 bits), words(16 bits), doublewords(32 bits), and quadwords(64 bits).   Are there others as well?

Comment: Which IA-32 variants? Including FPU? SSE/etc? Excluding ops specific to AMD-64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you missed one more --> `double quadwords [8 bytes](128 bits)`.

From Intel Manual:-

> The fundamental data types are bytes, words, doublewords, quadwords,
>   and double quadwords (see Figure 4-1). A byte is eight bits, a word is
>   2 bytes (16 bits), a doubleword is 4 bytes (32 bits), a quadword is 8
>   bytes (64 bits), and a double quadword is 16 bytes (128 bits). A
>   subset of the IA-32 architecture instructions operates on these
>   fundamental data types without any additional operand typing.

[image: Fundamental Types]

> The quadword data type was introduced into the IA-32 architecture in
>   the Intel486 processor; **the double quadword data type was introduced
>   in the Pentium III processor with the SSE extensions**.